# Group Query Results by Start of Week

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few different tables that I'm trying to join aggregate results out of and group them based on different time intervals.

```
calendar table
+------------+
| adate      |
+------------+
| 2015-09-24 |
| 2015-09-25 |
| 2015-09-26 |
| 2015-09-27 |
| 2015-09-28 |
....etc.......

plays table
+----+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | session_id | video_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |        1 | 2015-09-25 15:49:50 | 2015-09-25 15:49:50 |
+----+------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And the PHP/SQL:

```
switch ( TRUE ) {
  case ($interval->days <= 7):
  default:
    $group_by = 'DATE(dates.adate)';
    break;
  case in_array( $interval->days, range(8, 31) ):
    $group_by = 'CONCAT(YEAR(dates.adate), "/", WEEK(dates.adate))';
    break;
  case ($interval->days > 31):
    $group_by = 'YEAR(dates.adate), MONTH(dates.adate)';
    break;
}

$sql = '
  SELECT calendar.adate,
         IFNULL(g.event_count, 0) event_count
  FROM calendar
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DATE(events.created_at) created_at,
           COUNT(*) event_count
    FROM plays events
    WHERE events.video_id = %d
    AND   events.created_at >= %s
    AND   events.created_at < date_add(%s, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    GROUP BY DATE(events.created_at)
  ) g
  ON g.created_at = calendar.adate
  WHERE calendar.adate BETWEEN %s AND %s
  GROUP BY ' . $group_by . '
  ORDER BY adate;
';
```

I'd like to change the grouping based on the interval length, ie. if it's a week's worth of results then group by each day, a months worth of results should group by "week of 9/28/15", a years worth of results should group by mm/yyyy

Can you show how to group the result set accordingly? I feel like I am close but missing something here.

Comment: It looks like your code is already grouping the result set based on interval. what happens with the current way you are doing it? what is incorrect about the result that prompted this question?

Comment: @chiliNUT I think what might be happening is that the `event_count` isn't being aggregated into the `group by` clause, but rather, the `group by` is still only showing `events` on the particular date that it has chosen to `group by`. Does that even make any sense?